# How many bracelets with 5 red beads and 5 blue beads

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I am trying to determine the number of bracelets that can be made with 5 red and 5 blue beads. I am having some problems. As far as i can tell,there are $252\times1$ rotations of order 1, $2\times 4$ rotations of order 5, $6\times5$ reflections with 2 fixed points (one of each color) and $0\times5$ reflections with no fixed points.

The problem is that when i put this into the Cauchy-Frobenius Formula, I end up with $$\frac{1}{20}(252+8+30)=14.5$$ and this does not work. I really have no idea where I am missing manipulations. The only thing I can think of would be that perhaps there are $12\times5$ reflections with 2 fixed points because switching the two fixed points would somehow change something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By using Burnside’s Lemma, the answer would be

$(2^{10}(1)+2^{1}(4)+2^{2}(4)+2^{5}(1)+2^{5}(5)+2^{6}(5))/20=(1024(1) + 2(4) +4(4) +32(1) + 32(5) +64(5) )/20 = 78.$

Above I combined the symmetries of the same type instead of writing out a sum of twenty numbers.You can get more idea about Burnside's lemma from Wikipedia.

Comment: where did you get 1024 from? also 32 and 64? Would those be reflection?

Comment: @Rob I have edited the solution.

Comment: @Rob What happens is that you approach the problem from the point of view of the symmetries, and for each symmetry of the necklace (e.g. rotation clockwise by one bead, e.g. flipping across the horizontal axis, etc.), you count the NUMBER of colorings which are fixed by the symmetry. The sum of these, over all the symmetries, divided by the number of symmetries, is exactly the number of “essentially different” colorings you are trying to count.

Comment: alright... not sure i completely understand... also, maybe I am unaware of some types of symmetry but I was under the impression that the only symmetries present were flipping and rotation (that is what the problem allows for). Are you using other symmetries? I am still rather unsure of where you are getting all of these powers of 2 from. Perhaps it was poorly explained in my course but I don't recognize what you are doing exactly